# Replace while true loops

Tags: python, windows, optimization, while-loop

I was the other day trying to create on python a little program who would detect if the key x is pressed, if yes the program continue and do it's task. i found the way to do it with the package keyboard :

```
while True :
  if keyboard.is_pressed("x"):
     ...
```

But it appears that the while true loop after a long time, start bugging, and that brought to ask you, if it is possible to do a loop or something to detect a key press without causing lags like the window system events when you click on a shortcut then a program appears.
Thank you.

Comment: What operating system are you using ?

Comment: This is the reason that UI frameworks exist -- to do this right requires some careful choreography (event loops, multiple threads, etc).  Usually you don't want to poll a key press in your own loop, because while that loop is running nothing else can happen; you instead want to tell the system what key you're interested in, and have it call your function when that key gets pressed.

Comment: - I'm using microsoft window.

Comment: Yes samwise , i'm searching to do that. How can i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

The [keyboard documentation](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard) specifically says **NOT** to use the method you are using:

```
import keyboard

# Don't do this!
#
#while True:
#    if keyboard.is_pressed('x'):
#        print('x was pressed!')
#
# This will use 100% of your CPU and print the message many times.

# Do this instead
while True:
    keyboard.wait('x')
    print('x was pressed! Waiting on it again...')

# or this
keyboard.add_hotkey('x', lambda: print('x was pressed!'))
keyboard.wait()
```

I would recommend reading the documentation for your specific needs.

#### Note:

If you are looking to **bind** the specific key to a function, you could do something like this:

```
import keyboard

def on_x_key_press():
    print("'x' key pressed")

keyboard.on_press_key("x", on_x_key_press)
```

Answer (score 0):

Now your computer runs through that loop as fast as it can. I think you could add a limit on how many times the keyboard press is checked.

```
import time

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("x"):
        ...

    time.sleep(0.001) # the program just sleeps for 0.001 seconds
```

If the program still lags, try to increment the value of seconds to wait (for example: from 0.001 to 0.005).

Comment: Pay attention that you want to keep that number (seconds) as low as possible, because if it is too big, your program will seem to not work properly at all. For example: if this number is 1 second, then the user needs to press "x" just in time - if he doesn't do this, the program will wait for 1 second, and the process repeats.

Comment: I see, thank you !for the response, but does windows events work like this ? Because whenever i click on a shortcut the program pops, and i'm not lagging at all.

Comment: Well, not quite. First of all, Windows wasn't created using Python. It's made with the help of much faster programming languages, like C, C++ and ASM. However, not looking at the programming language itself, your program has only one thread happening when you run it. In Windows and other operating systems there are hundreds of those threads running at the same time, so that a lot of code would execute almost at once.